# Variable size bitset

Tags: c++, data-structures, bitset

I am practicing a question on array in which I have to find unique elements. Now for this my logic is to find the max element in the array and define the bitset for that. But problem is bitset needs a constant value so how to overcome this, below are some of my question on this:

a) Can I, by any chance, define the bitset with a variable size?
b) If not, then what is the best approach to use `vector<bool>` or `vector<char>`?
c) I know boost has a dynamic bitset but as I am doing this for learning I want to know of alternate approaches.

Comment: See [Boost.DynamicBitset](http://www.boost.org/libs/dynamic_bitset/).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The `std::bitset<N>` template requires a fixed size in advance.  The `std::vector<bool>` is the C++ standard's way of providing a variable-length bitvector, and it offers functionality similar to a bitset that can grow and shrink.

As for whether it's better or worse to use `vector<char>` or `vector<bool>`: the `vector<bool>` is a much more direct way of accomplishing this goal.  I would start off by using it, then switch to `vector<char>` if the performance is unacceptable.  In general, it's good to try to write the cleanest, most straightforward implementation first, then to optimize later on.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for quick reply ..:) ...okay that means bitset should only be used when size known beforehand ..?

Comment: @Himank- It's a stronger claim -  `std::bitset` *can* only be used when the size is known statically.

Comment: Thanks again..! and one more doubt what would be the best approach in vector(bool) and vector(char) for this type of question when I just need to find unique when size not known..?

Comment: @Himank- As mentioned in my answer, if you're planning on using a bit vector, the `vector<bool>` is a more reasonable starting point.  I would switch to `vector<char>` only if you suspected that `vector<bool>` wasn't performant.

Comment: Another thing, that you should know about `vector< bool >` is that `& v[ n ] - & v[ 0 ]` can be **not** equal to `n`, instead of any other type

Comment: @borisbn thanks for this ...but why so ..alignment issue ?

Comment: @Himank no. It's not because of alignment, but because of C++ standard  (23.2.4 and 23.2.5) says: "The elements of a vector are stored contiguously, meaning that if v is a vector<T, Allocator> where T is some type **other than bool**,  then it obeys the identity &v[n] == &v[0] + n for all 0 <= n < v.size()". `vector< bool >` can store 8 values in one byte