# how do i convert a string a bitset without specifying size of bits?

Tags: c++, bitset

i know we can convert a string to bitset by following way:

```
std::bitset<8> my_bitset(std::string("00011100");
```

but what if the string is being taken as input by user or from some file and the **size of string may vary.**

In above example we knew the size of string is 8, so we initialized the bitset size by 8.

I tried passing the size of string but got compilation error.

Comment: The short answer: you can't use bitset. The bitset's size must be specified at compile time. End of story. You'll have to use some other container.

Comment: if you have some small range of possible bitset lengths, it is possible, though will require cognitive leap to understand what the code does.

Comment: See variable size bitset question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14433626/variable-size-bitset)

Comment: @flatmouse it is suggesting me to go for ` vector<bool> `

Comment: Yes, it does suggest that. `std::vector<bool>` [might be better](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool) than something you come with yourself to store bits.

Comment: You might want to  try [boost::dynamic_bitset](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/boost/dynamic_bitset/dynamic_bitset.hpp)

Answer (score 0):

This question could be rephrased more generally as, "how do I execute compile-time generated code using runtime attributes?"

The basic answer is to build a compile-time array of pointers to the templatised functions that do the work, and then index into that array.

```
#include <bitset>
#include <cstdint>
#include <array>
#include <utility>

// define the parameters of supported lengths
struct traits
{
  static const std::size_t lowest = 1;
  static const std::size_t highest = 64;
  static const std::size_t extent = (highest - lowest) + 1;
};

//
// use a bitset of some length to decode the string
//
template<std::size_t Bits>
unsigned long long decode_impl(std::string const& s)
{
  std::bitset<Bits> bs(s);
  return bs.to_ullong();
}

//
// build an array of pointers to the decode functions, one for each Is
//
template<std::size_t...Is>
constexpr std::array<unsigned long long (*)(std::string const&), traits::extent>
decoders(std::index_sequence<Is...>)
{
  return {{
    &decode_impl<Is + traits::lowest>...
  }};
}

//
// build all pointers
//
std::array<unsigned long long (*)(std::string const&), traits::extent>
constexpr decoders()
{
  return decoders(std::make_index_sequence<traits::extent>());
}

//
// use runtime attributes to switch into compile-time constructs
//
unsigned long long decode(std::string const& s)
{
  static constexpr auto my_decoders = decoders();

  auto sz = std::max(s.size(), traits::lowest);
  if (sz > traits::highest)
    throw std::logic_error("unsupported length");
  return my_decoders[sz - traits::lowest](s);

}
```